# Static analysis, find unused permissions in an android application

Tags: static, analysis

I am trying to make a c++ program that is able to detect unused permissions in an android application. I was able to do reverse engineering process and get the java classes of the application. Then I used an xml parser to be able to get the list of permissions defined in Android manifest. Now I want to inspect the java classes to check the permissions that weren't used at all. I don't want to find the problem of checking permissions during run time or the permissions in the unreachable part of code. I just want to find the unused permissions that don't require dynamic analysis. If any one of you know a library that takes java classes and enables me to find the permission or an idea about the steps I should follow since googling isn't getting me anywhere. Thank you.